# Reusing old first partition with boot flag

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have my disk partitionned this way on my server :

```
parted -l
Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  56.6GB  56.6GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      56.6GB  120GB   63.4GB  extended
 6      56.6GB  116GB   59.3GB  logical   ext4
 5      116GB   120GB   4182MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Partition one is a very old ubuntu version but has boot flag. Nowadays I am using partition 6 with an up-to-date ubuntu version.

I'd like to reuse safely partition 1 to put some data or even one day install new OS (no windows).

I can mount sda1 to one dir, cd this dir, then rm -rf inside the dir.
Or can I reformat this partition ?

What is it the "proper" solution to manage this partition with boot flag ? 
Without taking any risk of course.

JP

Comment: It may be simpler to backup your data, and do a clean install of one of the current version of Ubuntu, erasing everything in the disk.

Comment: It may be possible to reformat the partition, then reinstall grub to the partition. Of course make backups before doing anything.

Comment: New install should have put its grub into MBR and you direct boot it. Is new install first in grub menu? Grub does not use boot flag, but some systems BIOS need a boot flag so we normally still suggest you have one. If grub is booting newer install, you  can do anything you want with sda1.

Comment: First, BACKUP! Then, succeed in moving the `BOOT` flag to another partition. Then, and only then, you can mess with the partition. Your system WILL boot from the partition with the `BOOT` flag. If you've overwritten it, the boot will FAIL.